# Active Record Relation Alias

Tags: activerecord, yii

i'm trying to set an alias to a relation by using the "with" method of ActiveRecord.
The problem is that i can only set the alias for the last element :

```
$ar->with(array('rel1.rel2' => array('alias' => 'rel2Alias'));
```

I have to retrieve the "rel1" and "rel2" for two columns of the AC class so i must set a different alias for the "rel1" relation but i don't know how to do.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try create two different relation in model for one model with different `ON`'s parametres

Answer (score 1):

if found the solution by reading closely the documentation :

```
$ar->with(array('rel1' => array('alias' => 'rel1Alias', 'with' => array('rel2' => array('alias' => 'rel2alias'))));
```